# Network structure for dual redundancy

Tags: networking, redundancy

Company is looking to upgrade their network with new equipment and while at it, I'd like to architect it to make it more secure, faster, etc.

The Agg Switch will have 1 connection to each Core Switch. The Access switch will have 1 connection to each Agg switch. (Not illustrated).

The company is okay with not having redundant router/firewall. We have extras to replace if needed.

We have two ISPs with 5 available IPs. My thought was to set it up this way:

```
                  RTR/FW IP 200.x.x.1 WAN PORT 1 -> Credit Processing company has their own network that can't connect behind our FW
                /
ISP2 -> L3 SWT 1                                       Core Switch 1 -> Agg Switch -> Access Switch
                 \                                    /
                  \                                  / 
                   = RTR/FW (Dual WAN) IP 100.x.x.1 =
                  /                                  \
 ISP1 -> L3 SWT 2                                     \ Core Switch 2 -> Agg Switch -> Access Switch
                  \ 
                   \ RTR/FW IP 200.x.x.1 WAN PORT 2-> Credit Processing....
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This question looks more suited to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely achieve certain level of security, redundant and fast n/w.

1. Make sure your router supports WAN fail over/load balance and load sharing. Load balance will make sure that at least you have WAN available in case of any of the ISP is down. And load sharing to make sure that you could utilize the both ISP at the same time.
2. As you said that you have five usable ip from both ISP so you have the choice of whether you would use those IP Addresses as WAN or you can ask your ISP's to provide separate WAN.
3. Use HSRP between core switch and Agg Switch, that is very easy to configure - if that is not available then you can try to achieve redundancy using STP also.
4. Use clustering at core switch level.They also provide cross connectivity for Agg switch.
5. Always make sure that trunk port is having higher throughput than access ports. You can check for the port upstream/downstream limit feature on access switch port level.
6. Apply storm control features at access switch port level.
7. Divide your Network into multiple subnet using VLAN for various department/floor level.
8. Apply strong NAT policy on firewall level.
9. Check for the firewall which supports UTM features like - Web Site Filtering, Antivirus, various level filters.

There are lot more others, it all depends on the features set provided by devices.

Comment: 1. The router is a Ubiquiti USG-Pro. It provides 2 WAN and 2 LAN ports. It allows for WAN failover. 2. The ISP will not provide more WAN ports. Will a layer 2 or layer 3 switch work for this? To provide more WAN ports.

Comment: That's OK if your ISP is not able to provide separate IP. You actually does not require more than 2 WAN if only 2 ISP are there. You should explore more on LAN side now. I don't have much idea on the router model, but I will check and see if something important is missing.